# How to grab values from url and pass them into action?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to fill up the html form for creating comment body so I can insert it into db by knowing `thread_id` and `user_id`. Now I'm having trouble getting the `thread_id`even tho its in url.

Now, I'm having routes that look like this:

```
        thread_path  GET     /manage/thread                               Rumbl.ThreadController :index
        thread_path  GET     /manage/thread/:id/edit                      Rumbl.ThreadController :edit
        thread_path  GET     /manage/thread/new                           Rumbl.ThreadController :new
        thread_path  GET     /manage/thread/:id                           Rumbl.ThreadController :show
        thread_path  POST    /manage/thread                               Rumbl.ThreadController :create
        thread_path  PATCH   /manage/thread/:id                           Rumbl.ThreadController :update
                     PUT     /manage/thread/:id                           Rumbl.ThreadController :update
        thread_path  DELETE  /manage/thread/:id                           Rumbl.ThreadController :delete
thread_comment_path  GET     /manage/thread/:thread_id/comments           Rumbl.CommentController :index
thread_comment_path  GET     /manage/thread/:thread_id/comments/:id/edit  Rumbl.CommentController :edit
thread_comment_path  GET     /manage/thread/:thread_id/comments/new       Rumbl.CommentController :new
thread_comment_path  GET     /manage/thread/:thread_id/comments/:id       Rumbl.CommentController :show
thread_comment_path  POST    /manage/thread/:thread_id/comments           Rumbl.CommentController :create
thread_comment_path  DELETE  /manage/thread/:thread_id/comments/:id       Rumbl.CommentController :delete
```

and action in controller that look like this

```
  def new(conn, %{"thread_id" => thread_id}) do
    changeset = Comment.changeset(
      %Comment{}, 
      %{user_id: conn.assigns.current_user.id,
        thread_id: thread_id
      })      
    render(conn,"new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"comment" => %{"content" => content}, "thread_id"=> thread_id}) do
    user_id = conn.assigns.current_user.id
    changeset = Comment.changeset(
      %Comment{
        content: content,
        user_id: user_id,
        thread_id: to_integer(thread_id)
      })

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _comment} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Comment created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: thread_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

From url `http://localhost:4000/manage/thread/7/comments/new`
I should be getting `thread_id = 7` but I'm getting it's `thread_id = 1` inside action create/2 for pattern match `"thread_id"=> thread_id`. Inside action new/2 I have `thread_id = 7` from hers pattern match so I thought to send it via connection but that didn't work. I'm guessing it's because the new conn from new.html got returned back?

Here is also that new.html file

```
<h2>New comment</h2>
<%= form_for @changeset, thread_comment_path(@conn,:create, @current_user), fn f -> %>

    <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
    <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :content, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= textarea f, :content, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :content %>
  </div>
    <%= submit "Create Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try `thread_comment_path(@conn, :create, @id_thread)` instead of `thread_comment_path(@conn,:create, @current_user)`.

Comment: Then I get the error ArgumentError at GET /manage/thread/7/comments/new
assign @id_thread not available in eex template.
Please make sure all proper assigns have been set. If this
is a child template, ensure assigns are given explicitly by
the parent template as they are not automatically forwarded.
Available assigns: [:changeset, :conn, :current_user, :view_module, :view_template]

Comment: Oops, try `thread_comment_path(@conn, :create, @changeset.data.thread_id)`.

Comment: `ArgumentError at GET /manage/thread/7/comments/new
cannot convert nil to param`
Even tho I see in `Params` in error web page that `thread_id` is "7"  :/

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the `thread_id` using the Ecto.Changeset [changes](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-the-ecto-changeset-struct) field.

```
<%= form_for @changeset, thread_comment_path(@conn,:create, @changeset.changes.thread_id), fn f -> %>
```

However this is a workaround by sending the changeset from action `new/2` and not really taking `thread_id` from the url `/manage/thread/7/comments/new`.

Comment: If you want to take it from `params`, you can do `@conn.params["thread_id"]` but usually I've seen `render conn, ..., thread_id: thread_id` and then `@thread_id` being used.

Comment: This also works but this is still passing some value from `new/2` into html and not really using the `/manage/thread/7/comments/new` to get the `thread_id`.